# How send an email with Grails 3 using smtp?

Tags: grails

I'm working in a project with Grails 3.0.1 and need send e-mails for users.

I was thinking send by smtp using a gmail account. I read about this plugin **":mail:1.0.7"** but don't gotten install on grails 3.0.1.

any way to send emails in this version?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a problem related [here](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/634) and solved in [2.0.0.RC2](https://github.com/grails3-plugins/mail/issues/3).

Now `compile 'org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0.RC1'` works with Grails 3.0.1

Answer (score 4):

Install the `mail` plugin by adding `compile 'org.grails.plugins:mail'` to your `build.gradle` and then read the doco [here](http://grails.org/plugin/mail).

In case you have trouble with the installation, try `compile 'org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0.RC1'`.

Comment: Works with `compile 'org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0.RC1'` 
**Thanks !!**

Comment: zoran119: How can get the documentation of mail 2.0.0.RC1 ? The doco of the link don't work with grails 3, por example the part "Configuration to Config.groovy" of the doco. Thanks!

Comment: I doubt much is changed in terms of configuration, you just put it into the `grails-app/conf/application.yml` file (in YAML format).

Comment: Yes @zoran119, i have this in application.yml file: http://pastebin.com/jDCnShV3, and this in my controller: http://pastebin.com/mqwgQSNc But when i try send a email, this is the log console: http://pastebin.com/36JcJhrC and never send... And my email are allowing external access.

Comment: In the log show 'compile  'org.grails.plugins:mail:2.0.0.RC1' but this is just a test, i try runtime too

Comment: Looks like the plugin is configured OK. Not sure why you cannot connect to gmail tho...

Comment: Please, can you test with an grails 2.4/2.5 project ?

Comment: I test with 2.5.1 and java 7 again, setting the user without @gmail and works, but in 3.0.1 with the same configuration, using `compile  'org.grails.plugins:mail:1.0.7'` don't work because don't `import grails.plugin.mail.MailService` this...